# Getting StackOverFlow Error (Java.lang.StackOverFlowError) in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, junit, junit4, hashset

I am struggling with the following code and test cases to pass. But getting a stack overflow error because of recursion calls from Link.java file.

I already tried to increase the stack size of JVM as some post from stack overflow suggested it, but it couldn't help.

Can anyone give me some solution to solve all of the test cases from LinkTest.java file?

Link.java

```
public class Link {
    private HashSet<Link> links = new HashSet<Link>();

    public void linkTo(Link link) {
        links.add(link);
    }

    public Boolean isLinkedTo(Link to) {
        Link link;

        while (!links.isEmpty()) {
            link = links.iterator().next();


            if (link == to || link.isLinkedTo(to) == true) {
                if (link == to) {
                    return true;
                } else if (link != to && link.isLinkedTo(to) == true) {
                    return true;
                } else if (link != to && link.isLinkedTo(to) == false) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (link != to || link.isLinkedTo(to) == false) {
                if (link == to) {
                    return true;
                } else if (link.isLinkedTo(to) == true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }
}
```

LinkTest.java

```
public class LinkTest extends TestCase
{
    @org.junit.Test
    public void testItCanLinkToItself()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        foo.linkTo(foo);
        assertTrue(foo.isLinkedTo(foo));
    }

    public void testItDoesNotLinkToItself()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        assertFalse(foo.isLinkedTo(foo));
    }


    public void testUnidirectionalLinkToNeighbour()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        Link bar = new Link();
        bar.linkTo(foo);
        assertTrue(bar.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertFalse(foo.isLinkedTo(bar));
    }

    public void testNeighboursWithConnectionsToThemselves()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        Link bar = new Link();
        Link baz = new Link();

        // Connect the Objs to themselves.
        foo.linkTo(foo);
        bar.linkTo(bar);
        baz.linkTo(baz);

        // Connect baz => bar => foo.
        baz.linkTo(bar);
        bar.linkTo(foo);



        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(bar));
        assertTrue(bar.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertFalse(bar.isLinkedTo(baz));
    }

    public void testCyclicGraph()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        Link bar = new Link();
        Link baz = new Link();

        // Connect the nodes baz => bar => foo => baz.
        baz.linkTo(bar);
        bar.linkTo(foo);
        foo.linkTo(baz);

        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(bar));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(baz));
    }

    public void testItCanHaveNeighboursInCyclicGraph()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        Link bar = new Link();
        Link baz = new Link();

        // Connect the nodes baz => bar <=> foo.
        baz.linkTo(bar);
        bar.linkTo(foo);
        foo.linkTo(bar);

        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(bar));
        assertFalse(baz.isLinkedTo(baz));

    }

    public void testCanHaveACycleOfMoreThanTwo()
    {
        Link foo = new Link();
        Link bar = new Link();
        Link baz = new Link();
        Link qux = new Link();

        // Connect the nodes baz => bar => foo => qux => bar.
        baz.linkTo(bar);
        bar.linkTo(foo);
        foo.linkTo(qux);
        qux.linkTo(bar);

       assertFalse(qux.isLinkedTo(baz));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(foo));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(bar));
        assertTrue(baz.isLinkedTo(qux));
       assertFalse(baz.isLinkedTo(baz));

    }

}
```

Comment: There's so many redundant tests and unreachable statements in your `isLinkedTo` method that it's hard to follow. The problem is that you're creating an infinite recursive loop, which should become apparent once you've cleaned those things up.

Comment: while (!links.isEmpty()) is an infinite loop because you never remove anything from the links. Thus recursion goes on forever. As said by Joseph, your linkedTo method also contains many unreachable and redundant if checks.

Comment: Before using `Link` in a `HashSet`, you **should** override [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) in `Link` (and also override [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work as your tests describe.

```java
public boolean isLinkedTo(Link to) {
    // start recursion with no currently checked links
    return isLinkedTo(to, new HashSet<>());
}

private boolean isLinkedTo(Link to, Set<Link> linksChecked) {
    // this link is linked to 'to'
    if (links.contains(to)) {
        return true;
    }
    // this link not linked to 'to' so add it to the checked links
    linksChecked.add(this);
    // check all links to see if the links are linked to 'to'
    for (Link link: links) {
        // current link not checked yet and current link is linked to 'to'
        if (!linksChecked.contains(link) && link.isLinkedTo(to, linksChecked)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // no links or sub-links are linked to 'to'
    return false;
}
```

To recursively check self linking links without infinite recursion, you must track what links you have already checked to avoid checking the same links infinitely. That is why I have added a helper method that tracks the checked links.

As the comment above by Elliott says though, when using a hashset of objects, you want to override the equals and hashcode methods of the class to ensure the hashset works as expected. Most ides can auto generate a valid equals hashcode for a class for you just as a side note.